# Fetching value from <option> tag and updating in database in JSP

Tags: database, jsp

I have made a dropdown list and the content is from the database, i could fetch id and name and display name on drop down list. but i want to store only id in the next page: see the code below:

```
 <%
         try{
             // Register JDBC driver
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

             // Open a connection
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infoshare", "root", "");

             // Execute SQL query
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM department WHERE status='A'");

             %>
              <select name="departments" style="padding:2px;">
               <option value ="000" disabled selected> Select Department</option>
             <%              
                while (rs.next()){ %>
                <option value=<%=rs.getInt("Department_id") %> > <%=rs.getString("Department_name") %> </option>                    
                <% }%>
                </select>
                <%
             // Clean-up environment
             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             //Handle errors for JDBC
             se.printStackTrace();
          }catch(Exception e){
             //Handle errors for Class.forName
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

        %>
```

once the form is submitted, i could get name but not able to get the value of tag, i want the value of option tag, how do i get the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i answer your question to get the selected value from Dropdown , use finally in your code to close all connection, statement resultset etc.

and to get the selected value you have to modify your select tag like below and should create a hidden field in JSP :

```
<select  id="name" name="name" onchange="updateName(value)">

<input type="hidden" name="selectedText" id="selectedText" value=""/>
```

you have to call a javascript call to fetch the selected text and assign the selected value in hidden parameter like.

```
document.getElemetById("selectedText").value = selectedText;
```

for better understanding refer this :
http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/y8e4B/